# Correlating parallel arrays in C#

Tags: c#

How can I associate two unidentical( arrays of different types) string arrays using C#?

Comment: Please rephrase the question:)

Comment: `( arrays of different types) string arrays` ? Which is it ? (Try to share some code to make the question clearer) If you are using C# 4, the Zip extension method might be what you want.

Comment: could you post some (pseudo) code that gives an example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

```
int lenght = 3;

string[] arr1 = new string [length] { "one", "two", "three", };
int[] arr2 = new int [length] { 1, 2, 3, };

string search = "two";
for (a = 0; a < lenght; a++)
{
    if (arr1[a] == search)
        Console.WriteLine("Element found at position {0}. The corresponding element is {1}", a + 1, arr2[a]);
}
```

I'm not sure if this is what you mean or not but you are better off using two dimensional arrays if you want rows and columns.